# How to create a multi flip button in iPhone like a pickerview

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I want to create a small sub view which has 3 buttons(say A,B,C) in it. The view should have an infinite scroll so that it should create a circular loop for those buttons when I scroll ie. if I scroll the view, the buttons' order should be like **A->B->C->A->B->C**....and so on. Also if I scroll from say, A to B and as soon as the B button appears at the center of the view, the action for that button should be performed. So which ever button appears at the center due to the scroll, the action for that particular button should be performed(something like pickerview). Among those 3 buttons I mentioned, one button should be at the center and the other 2 buttons on the left and right should be half hidden, so that the user knows there are other buttons inside the view.

To sum up, I want exactly like this flip button shown in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://code4app.net/ios/loop-ScrollView/4fdaa4676803faab3d000000

Go through the above link for the source code for the circular loop scroll, which by the way would suit your needs for the ***infinite scrollview***.

You can even customize that open source code by using ***tap to scroll function*** in the **handle tap** method in ***Cyclescrollview.m*** class,

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {

    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 30, 70, 40) animated:YES];

     NSLog(@"Tap");
}
```

Or you can even scroll the images to perform any actions you want by using this method for the scroll features,

```
- (void)cycleScrollViewDelegate:(CycleScrollView *)cycleScrollView didScrollImageView:(int)index

 {
    if (index==1)
        {
    NSLog(@"First image scrolled");
}
   if (index==2)
        {
    NSLog(@"Second image scrolled");
}
   if (index==3)
        {
   NSLog(@"Third image scrolled");
}

}
```

And you can also reduce the spacing between the images in order for them to appear like you mentioned "One button should be at the center and the other two should be half hidden"

Good luck with your Flip button.